# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1) \ ^{ k+1} ak <\infty$ for $a_n\downarrow 0$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $a_{n+1}\le a_n$, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Prove that the following series is convergent:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1) \ ^{ k+1} a_k $$

I started by thinking that there is $n_0$ s.t for every $n>n_0$,  $a_n <1$ and then I thought , using compassing to geometric progression with $q = a_{n_0}$. 
Am I in the right direction ?

Comment: You could search about the Leibniz Criterion, this can solve your problem, look the proof of the Criterion of Leibniz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Denote $(S_n)$ the given sequence (partial sum). Prove that the two sequences $(S_{2n})$ and $(S_{2n+1})$ are adjacent. Conclude.